# Rshiny tab display by click on the menuitems in the sidebarmenu

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display data in the mainpanel,by just clicking on the menuitems in my sidebarmenu.

So i have some menuitems like

Preprocessing
EDA
Text Classification

I want to open tabs with content specific to each of the menu items when i click on these menuitems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need provide an example. Just description of what you need is not enough. Post what have you tried so far, and where you are stuck. If error, reproduce the error with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateTabsetPanel` ([help](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateTabsetPanel.html)) to change the selected tab.